# Schema based facets in Vespa

Tags: vespa

Is there any way to implement schema based facets in Vespa?

For Eg:
My schema contains the fields: album, artist and year. For that the schema facet would be:

[{"field":".fields", "label":"artist", "count":300},{"field":".fields", "label":"album", "count":300},{"field":".fields", "label":"year", "count":250}]

Answer (score 2):

Facets in Vespa is called result grouping, see https://docs.vespa.ai/en/grouping.html

Comment: How do I get all the field names present in a particular schema?

Comment: Open the schema file definition in an editor of your choice? Only fields with attribute as part of their indexing schema is available for grouping.

Comment: What I meant to ask was- Is there any way to get that particular information using Query API?